# Every golang object inherits from what object?

Tags: object, go

I have a function

```
func outputJsonForModel(w http.ResponseWriter, obj []Obj) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(b))
}
```

What type do I make the parameter `obj []Obj` so that I can pass in any object?

Comment: There are no objects in go, and no inheritance.

Comment: Oh okay, I see why now, thanks. I'm new to go, but not new to programming.

Comment: Replace  the statement `fmt.Fprintf(w, string(b))` with the simpler and higher performing statement `w.Write(b)` .

Comment: I would imagine it's being downvoted because you didn't even do the minimal research to know that Go has no objects or inheritence. This is usually covered in the very first section of any intro to Go.

Comment: Also note the incorrect assumption that an object must inherent from a base class/type. While some OO languages do this, not all do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics don't (yet) exist in Go, but you could use an interface type to be able to pass in any type.

If you look at the code from the Marshal function itself, you will see that it also uses an interface type.

[json.Marshal](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go?s=6458:6501#L148)

```
func Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    e := newEncodeState()
    err := e.marshal(v, encOpts{escapeHTML: true})

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    buf := append([]byte(nil), e.Bytes()...)

    encodeStatePool.Put(e)

    return buf, nil

}
```